# PHP upload file to BLOB

Tags: php, file, file-upload, blob

So the issue I am having is it seems I cant send the file I want to the server.

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, but thought I would ask

```
 <?

$file = file_get_contents($HTTP_POST_FILES['img']);
print $file;

?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="file" name="img" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: what you're trying to achieve with `print $file;` ?

Comment: And use `$_FILES` not `$HTTP_POST_FILES`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the correct `enctype` to [multipart/form-data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) on the form if you want to be able to upload files to the server:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="img" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure if I am doing something wrong

Sure. You haven't read the manual page.

here you are: http://php.net/upload